I cannot see navigation bar in SwiftUI view
I tried to add NavigationStack and also NavigationView into this view but I cannot get the navigation bar. What prevents this view from creating a navigation bar at the top?
Below is the code I tried.
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            VStack {
                selectedView
                Spacer()
                HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                    TabBarItem(label: "Listings", iconName: "house.fill", action: {
                        selectedTab = 0
                        selectedView = AnyView(homeView)
                    })
                    TabBarItem(label: "Favorites", iconName: "heart.fill", action: {
                        selectedTab = 1
                        selectedView = AnyView(FavoritesView(userId: $userId, firestoreService: firestoreService, storageService: storageService, messagingService: messagingService))
                    })
                    Text("Create")
                    TabBarItem(label: "Messages", iconName: "message.fill", action: {
                        selectedTab = 2
                        selectedView = AnyView(ConversationsView(messagingService: messagingService, storageService: storageService, userId: $userId))
                    })
                    TabBarItem(label: "Profile", iconName: "person.fill", action: {
                        selectedTab = 3
                        selectedView = AnyView(ProfileView(role: role ?? "Sitter"))
                    })
                }
                .font(.footnote)
                .padding(.top, 42)
                .overlay(alignment: .top) {
                    Button {
                        selectedView = AnyView(CreateListingView(role: role))
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus") // "plus_icon"
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .padding()
                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                            .foregroundStyle(.white)
                            .background {
                                Circle()
                                    .fill(.green) // custom64B054Color
                                    .shadow(radius: 3)
                            }
                    }
                    .padding(9)
                }
                .padding(.bottom, max(8, proxy.safeAreaInsets.bottom))
                .background {
                    TabBarShape()
                        .fill(.white)
                        .shadow(radius: 3)
                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
            .onReceive(firestoreService.$listings, perform: { _ in
                selectedView = AnyView(homeView)
            })
        }
    }
}

tabBar

This isn’t UIKit you need a .toolbar. Also AnyView is highly discouraged.

Toolbar as a modifier of Vstack or GeometryReader?

For any View note that GeometryReader should only be used as a last resort too. It is terribly inefficient.

I want to emphasize SwiftUI is not like UIKit you are coding like one does with UIKit. This is not will not be viable for a production environment. That whole “selected view” this is not the way SwiftUI works

https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui-concepts/

what is your suggestions then to use that custom TabBar at the bottom? the solution i could find was this.

I think you should review the Apple tutorials. So you can get a bit of insight of the differences maybe even look for the “Demystify SwiftUI” video. idk What your TabBar looks like but you should not be putting a View in an AnyView property. SwiftUI is model based, models that conform to Hashable, Equatable and Identifiable tell SwiftUI what to display and SwiftUI tells the body when to reload based on those protocols (they are all used in different situations). I would probably use SwiftUI.Layout for placement of the major sections because it is more efficient/safer than GeometryReader

thank you very much. for a clarity i am adding my tabbar view along with the other elements inside contentView to my post
